# Is there an equivalent to the word sibling for a parent-child relationship?

Tags: single-word-requests

Does a parent-child relationship have an equivalent to the word "sibling"?

For example:

> Brother to brother: "We are brothers. We are siblings"
>
> Son to father: "We are ________."

I do not know of a word in English to express parent-child relations like that other than in terms of one to the other (i.e. "*you* are *my* father; *I* am *your* son"). The closet I can think of is using the family name ("we are Lannisters").

Comment: There might be, but it would be contrived and little used, because unlike brother-to-brother relationships, the parent-child relationship is asymmetric. You may not care which particular brother you're dealing with, but you almost always care about whether you're dealing with the parent or the child. And of course children treat their parents differently than parents treat their children.

Comment: A person's ***next-of-kin*** (NOK) is that person's closest living blood relative or relatives. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Next_of_kin

Comment: A simple answer: no, there isn't.  You should say "We are father and son", or "This is my son" or "This is my father".

Comment: We just say, "[father and son](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=father+and+son&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Hc7cWOvLH8v48Aeh4ICQBA)."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Kin or family. There's nothing specific to the case.